# How to get name instead if Id

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

I want to fetch all data but in instead of id in supervisor and team leader I want to get their name or email id

Ex

If I fetch id 8 data it should come like this:

```
id -> 8
user_name -> ag2
password -> 121212
email -> ag2@ag.com
mobile->21341234
superwisor -> kk(user_name of Id 1)
teamleader -> tl2(user_name of id 4)
```

Comment: Looks like you are storing PASSWORDS as PLAINTEXT. **Thats Beau Coup Bad** PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them for the safety of your users.

Comment: You need to study RDMS. You can resolve this issue using **join**.
**Note:** __you should use InnoDB referential integrity to relate this table with superwisor and teamleader tables.__

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `self join` as follows:

```
Select e.id, e.user_name, e.email, e.password, e.mobile, 
       s.user_name as superwisor, t.user_name as team_leader
From your_table e
Left join your_table s on s.id = e.superwisor
Left join your_table t on t.id = e.teamleader;
```